# aws cli: EC2: get the state of list of instances

Tags: aws-cli

I am trying to get the status of few EC2 instance using AWS CLI

```
   aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids xxxxxx yyyyyyyy zzzzzzzz
```

But in the output It only lists the instances which are running and not which are stopped.

How can i view the instances state even they are running or stopped

Answer (score 10):

There are different ways to check the `instance-state`.

### Use:

**describe-instance-status.**

> You can use `describe-instance-status`: The `describe-instance-status` command of the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) is used to retrieve the status of one or more Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instances. By default, it returns the status of running instances. To include stopped instances in the returned status information, you can use the `--include-all-instances` option.

Here is an example of how you can use this option:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instance-status --include-all-instances
```

the above command will return the status information for both running and stopped instances.

Note that you can also filter the returned results using the `--filters` option. For example, you can use the following command to only retrieve the status of stopped instances:

```
$aws ec2 describe-instance-status --filters "Name=instance-state-code,Values=80"
```

Note: here `80` is the code for `stopped` instances and `16` for `running` ones. Below one will give you the info about `stopped` instance .

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instance-status --include-all-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values='stopped'
```

> You can get both the `running` as well as `stooped` `instance-state` while including the option  `--include-all-instances` as used in the below given example...

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instance-status --include-all-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values='*' --query 'InstanceStatuses[*].{InstanceId: InstanceId, State: InstanceState.Name}' --profile lab--output table


------------------------------------
|      DescribeInstanceStatus      |
+----------------------+-----------+
|      InstanceId      |   State   |
+----------------------+-----------+
|  i-0a4209dkc6549a2ea |  running  |
|  i-09379cj420ed015f2 |  running  |
|  i-0c9e1100de0105ed6 |  stopped  |
|  i-0f57b147ea9124344 |  running  |
|  i-02e4cbcbe10cb5e79 |  stopped  |
+----------------------+-----------+
```

**describe-instances.**

> You can check the `instance-state-name`  regardless of the `state` of the instance `(pending | running | shutting-down | terminated | stopping | stopped )` while using with `describe-instances`.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[*].{InstanceType: InstanceType, InstanceId: InstanceId, State: State.Name}' --profile lab --output table
----------------------------------------------------
|                 DescribeInstances                |
+----------------------+----------------+----------+
|      InstanceId      | InstanceType   |  State   |
+----------------------+----------------+----------+
|  i-0a4209dkc6549a2ea |  t3.xlarge     |  running |
|  i-09379cj420ed015f2 |  t2.small      |  running |
|  i-0c9e1100de0105ed6 |  m5.xlarge     |  stopped |
|  i-0f57b147ea9124344 |  c6i.xlarge    |  running |
|  i-02e4cbcbe10cb5e79 |  t1.micro      |  stopped |
+----------------------+----------------+----------+
```

> However, you can get a specific `state` of an instance using `--filers` and `--query`, for example, if you are looking for only a `stopped` instance then you can use like below...

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[*].{InstanceType: InstanceType, InstanceId: InstanceId, State: State.Name}' --profile lab --output table
----------------------------------------------------
|                 DescribeInstances                |
+----------------------+----------------+----------+
|      InstanceId      | InstanceType   |  State   |
+----------------------+----------------+----------+
|  i-0c9e1100de0105ed6 |  m5.xlarge     |  stopped |
|  i-02e4cbcbe10cb5e79 |  t1.micro      |  stopped |
+----------------------+----------------+----------+
```

In a similar fashion, you can check only the `running` instance …

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[*].{InstanceType: InstanceType, InstanceId: InstanceId, State: State.Name}' --profile lab --output table
----------------------------------------------------
|                 DescribeInstances                |
+----------------------+----------------+----------+
|      InstanceId      | InstanceType   |  State   |
+----------------------+----------------+----------+
|  i-0a4209dkc6549a2ea |  t3.xlarge     |  running |
|  i-09379cj420ed015f2 |  t2.small      |  running |
+----------------------+----------------+----------+
```

### Note:

Further, I personally like to dictionary format along with tabular output(`--output table`) while using AWS CLI to get the values in nice tabular form which is easy for readability, hence the same here to get the values of the `instance-state` in a hash form (i.e., a dictionary or associative array), you I have combined that with the `--query` to get a nicer readable output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you pass the `--include-all-instances` option to the command it will also show stopped instances

From AWS documentation about the [describe-instance-status](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-status.html) command:

> `--include-all-instances | --no-include-all-instances (boolean)`
>
> When true , includes the health status for all instances. When false, includes the health status for running instances only.
>
> Default: false